# When to release build increment?

Tags: ros, bloom-release, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Related to a discussion at [this release request](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/pull/1890#issuecomment-23458646).

Even looking at this, I still feel like making only build-increment release, when I add to upstream/development repository that's only a change that has nothing to do with functionality. Especially when the change is an attempt to pass buildfarm, which I think ideally should have been included in the "first" release (ie. 0 build increment) but somehow missed and found on buildfarm. I just want to confirm in the situation like this do we still need to release a new version? If it is defined I'd appreciate that.
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/76150/when-to-release-build-increment?/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2013-09-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you change the upstream repository then you must increase the upstream version. Period. If you don't want to have to make a lot of patch releases, then you should make sure it builds before you commit it to the farm.

The release increment is only to be used for when you change the release of the package without touching the upstream. This includes running the release again for new rosdep rules, running for new release targets (like os or platform), or to add a patch in the release repository (should ideally be reserved for third party packages).

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2